# I need help with this integral: $ \int \frac{1}{(a+b \cos x)^{2}} \, \mathrm dx $?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I need some help evaluating the integral 
$$ \int \frac{1}{(a+b \cos x)^{2}} \, \mathrm dx .$$ 
I have achieved a result by using the substitution of letting $ \tan(x/2) = t $,  but it is quite cumbersome and big afterwards. Please suggest some shorter methods if possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maple also uses the tan-half angle substitution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality, $a>b>0$
$$ I(a)=\int\frac{1}{a+b\cos x}dx $$
and then
$$ I'(a)=-\int\frac{1}{(a+b\cos x)^2}dx. $$
Using $u=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
I(a)&=&\int\frac{1}{a+b\cos x}dx\\
&=&\int\frac{2}{(a-b)u^2+(a+b)}du\\
&=&\frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{a-b}{a+b}}u)\\
&=&\frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{a-b}{a+b}}\tan(\frac{x}{2})).
\end{eqnarray}
Hence
$$ \int\frac{1}{(a+b\cos x)^2}dx=-I'(a)=... $$
It is straight forward to get $I'(a)$ and omit the detail. For other cases of $a$ and $b$, you can use the same way to discuss.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

WLOG, $b=1$ for simplicity. Let $z=e^{ix}$, so that $dx=\dfrac{dz}{iz}$.

$$\int\frac{dz}{4iz(4a+z+z^{-1})^2}=\frac1{4i}\int\frac{z\,dz}{(z^2+4az+1)^2}=\frac1{4i}\int\frac{(w-2a)\,dz}{(w^2+1-a^2)^2}.$$